# Getting Error : Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Getting Error while using Hook:-

i have already done 
 $config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE; in autoload.php and also set encryption key..

config/Hook.php

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'Login_hook',
                                'function' => 'check_login_hook',
                                'filename' => 'Login_hook.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks'
                                );
```

hooks/Login_hook.php

```
<?php
class Login_hook extends CI_Controller{
    function check_login_hook(){

        if(isset($this->session->userdata['user_storage'])){
            echo $user_id=$this->session->userdata['user_storage']['s_u_id'];
            echo $user_id=$this->session->userdata['user_storage']['s_u_name'];
        }else{
            echo "n";
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Error is:-

```
Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Load library session in construct

```
class check_login_hook extends CI_Controller {
     public function __construct()
          {
             parent::__construct();
             $this->load->library('session');
          }
```

Open your autoload.php in applications/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Answer (score 0):

Open you config.php in

```
$config['base_url'] ='your base url';
```

also enable the helper class in autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```